# Escape colons, equals, ampersands in arguments

Tags: bash, command-line, escaping, quotes

Below is my code, which behaves extremely bizarre, and I am not sure I understand the reason, but I think it's somehow connected to path expansion:

**EDIT:** this is the `asxgrab` script mentioned in the second listing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

let "i=0"

GET "$1" | grep 'href="mms://' | while read line
do
    echo "$line"
    address=`echo $line | grep -Eow '"[^"]+"'`
    address_length=$((${#address}-2))
    address=${address:1:address_length}
    echo "Grabbing '$address', attempt $i, $address_length"
    mplayer "'$address' -dumpstream -dumpfile '$2.wmv' -vf scale\=320\:240" > /dev/null
    if [ ! $? ]; then
        break 1
    fi
    let "i++"
done
```

I've tried dozens of different ways of escaping, quoting and whatnot, and I think I've exhausted my creativity... please help!

Suppose the script is called with these arguments:

```
./asxgrab 'http://switch3.castup.net/cunet/gm.asp?ai=16&ip=79.180.37.230&course=c20478/2012b&cuud=user:77f6c69526b9fa05f78d3d6679630308d324d1043027b0720c295b93e4abb183&ar=c20478_12b_784_01_1&ticket=58353E7A69BF1B9XO655E9E683016C5255C08DD37211ECF495F72A64E5278AA434CSP3C10C028D604AAD6C39FE7D71386D230983BBAF58A2511D14222F95090AE2C4C55CB696B82919A5A8EB44EAF8954DEDB5' 'java.0'
```

The received response looks like this:

```
<asx version="3.0">
    <!-- GMX -->
    <param name="encoding" value="utf-8" />
    <title>CastUP: c20478_12b_784_01_1</title>
    <MOREINFO HREF = "" />

    <entry>
    <PARAM NAME="EntryType" VALUE="Content" />

    <param name="encoding" value="utf-8" />
    <PARAM NAME="CastUP_AssociatedURL" VALUE="" />
    <PARAM NAME="CastUP_Content_Config" VALUE="" />
    <PARAM NAME="CastUP_Content_ClipMediaID" VALUE="9067325" />
    <author>openu</author>
        <title>CastUP: c20478_12b_784_01_1</title>
<ref href="mms://s3fwm.castup.net/server12/16/798/79837168-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=16&ts=0&cu=FE81687B-33CD-4441-A8F6-1DEC9923332C&cuud=user:77f6c69526b9fa05f78d3d6679630308d324d1043027b0720c295b93e4abb183&cuud=user:77f6c69526b9fa05f78d3d6679630308d324d1043027b0720c295b93e4abb183" />
<ref href="...." />

    </entry>
```

When I do this:

```
mplayer "mms://s3fwm.castup.net/server12/16/798/79837168-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=16&ts=0&cu=C6527A33-587F-4148-A3D2-E7EDED51316B&cuud=user:77f6c69526b9fa05f78d3d6679630308d324d1043027b0720c295b93e4abb183&cuud=user:77f6c69526b9fa05f78d3d6679630308d324d1043027b0720c295b93e4abb183" -dumpstream -dumpfile java0.wmv -vf scale=320:240
```

from the terminal, it works, but it doesn't work from the script. Instead it tries to trim the `$line` or something like that. I don't even understand what happens, but the output is absolutely of no consequences...

This is my uni's site and this is, funny as it gets, a lecture on Java :)

**EDIT:**

```
<ref href="mms://s0dwm.castup.net/server12/16/798/79837168-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=16&ts=0&cu=111A3770-29DC-40EC-85EC-93453E2819D7&cuud=user:77f6c69526b9fa05f78d3d6679630308d324d1043027b0720c295b93e4abb183&cuud=user:77f6c69526b9fa05f78d3d6679630308d324d1043027b0720c295b93e4abb183" />
Grabbing 'mms://s0dwm.castup.net/server12/16/798/79837168-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=16&ts=0&cu=111A3770-29DC-40EC-85EC-93453E2819D7&cuud=user:77f6c69526b9fa05f78d3d6679630308d324d1043027b0720c295b93e4abb183&cuud=user:77f6c69526b9fa05f78d3d6679630308d324d1043027b0720c295b93e4abb183', attempt 0, 268
Can't open joystick device /dev/input/js0: No such file or directory
Can't init input joystick
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.
No stream found to handle url 'mms://s0dwm.castup.net/server12/16/798/79837168-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=16&ts=0&cu=111A3770-29DC-40EC-85EC-93453E2819D7&cuud=user:77f6c69526b9fa05f78d3d6679630308d324d1043027b0720c295b93e4abb183&cuud=user:77f6c69526b9fa05f78d3d6679630308d324d1043027b0720c295b93e4abb183' -dumpstream -dumpfile 'java.0.wmv' -vf scale=320:240
d324d1043027b0720c295b93e4abb183" />
Grabbing '', attempt 1, -2
Can't open joystick device /dev/input/js0: No such file or directory
Can't init input joystick
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.
File not found: ''' -dumpstream -dumpfile 'java.0.wmv' -vf scale=320:240'
Failed to open '' -dumpstream -dumpfile 'java.0.wmv' -vf scale=320:240.
027b0720c295b93e4abb183" />
```

This is the output I'm getting from the script.

```
MPlayer SVN-r31918 (C) 2000-2010 MPlayer Team
Can't open joystick device /dev/input/js0: No such file or directory
Can't init input joystick
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing mms://s3fwm.castup.net/server12/16/798/79837168-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=16&ts=0&cu=C6527A33-587F-4148-A3D2-E7EDED51316B&cuud=user:77f6c69526b9fa05f78d3d6679630308d324d1043027b0720c295b93e4abb183&cuud=user:77f6c69526b9fa05f78d3d6679630308d324d1043027b0720c295b93e4abb183.
STREAM_ASF, URL: mms://s3fwm.castup.net/server12/16/798/79837168-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=16&ts=0&cu=C6527A33-587F-4148-A3D2-E7EDED51316B&cuud=user:77f6c69526b9fa05f78d3d6679630308d324d1043027b0720c295b93e4abb183&cuud=user:77f6c69526b9fa05f78d3d6679630308d324d1043027b0720c295b93e4abb183
Resolving s3fwm.castup.net for AF_INET6...

Couldn't resolve name for AF_INET6: s3fwm.castup.net
Resolving s3fwm.castup.net for AF_INET...
Connecting to server s3fwm.castup.net[212.179.13.65]: 1755...

Connected
file object, packet length = 6100 (6100)
unknown object
unknown object
unknown object
stream object, stream ID: 1
stream object, stream ID: 2
unknown object
data object
mmst packet_length = 6100
Cache size set to 64 KBytes
Stream not seekable!
```

And this is the expected output.

Comment: You did not tell a single word on what it should do :-) I was able to decipher that you read a file (what ./asxgrab does) then you throw that text file to your script which greps the lines with `href="mms://` then it iterates through the matching lines.

Comment: Do the `echo "$line"` and `echo "Grabbing '$address', attempt $i, $address_length"` commands print what you expect?

Comment: Okay, but as I understand the problem is how to extract the video URL from the asx file properly, which you want to throw to `mplayer` (as you wrote, it works from terminal but not from script)

Comment: When I run your script, `$line` seems to have a `'\r'` (or, if you prefer, a CTRL-M) appended to it.  Is this relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
mplayer "$address" -dumpstream -dumpfile "$2.wmv" -vf "scale=320:240" > /dev/null
```

Secrets of bash:

- Variables inside double-quotes are expanded; those inside single-quotes are not.
- Words inside quotes are treated as a single token.
- Quotes of one type escape those of the other type.

The original line

```
mplayer "'$address' -dumpstream -dumpfile '$2.wmv' -vf scale\=320\:240" > /dev/null
```

called `mplayer` with the single argument `'$address' -dumpstream -dumpfile '$2.wmv' -vf scale\=320\:240`, but `mplayer` wants each of those tokens to be a separate word.

Comment: @wvxvw: But the quotes around `scale=320:240` have no effect; there must be something else that you missed before. :-/

Comment: another on GREP: grep is a line tool which means if you have a 2 TB file and you `grep` it, you'll be immediately get back matches, if there is any, you don't have to wait for the whole file to be processed. This means that grep will return 1 line at a time therefore that `while read line` block is unnecessary (as it will process a one-line text input).

Comment: @wvxvw: You have a working script now, right? Well, try changing `"scale=320:240"` back to `scale=320:240` (as in my answer), and you'll find that it still works. You must have changed something else at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding everything correctly, the only real problem I see is that this line:

```
    mplayer "'$address' -dumpstream -dumpfile '$2.wmv' -vf scale\=320\:240" > /dev/null
```

is supposed to be this:

```
    mplayer "$address" -dumpstream -dumpfile "$2.wmv" -vf scale=320:240 > /dev/null
```

That is, you need to remove the double-quotes that gather all of `mplayer`'s arguments into a single argument, and you need to remove the single-quotes around, and backslashes inside, some of those arguments.

Other things I might change for cleanliness' sake:

- changing `read line` to `read -r line` would eliminate any potential weirdness from backslashes.
- a line `line="${line%$'\r'}"` at the beginning of the `while`-loop body would lay to rest any concern about stray carriage-returns.
- changing `` address=`echo $line ... `` to `` address=`echo "$line" ... `` would eliminate any risk of word-splitting and filename-expansion and whatnot (not that they seem very likely as it is).
- the `[ ! $? ]` test is meaningless (since `$?` is never blank, is it?); changing it to just `&& break 1` at the end of the previous command would be clearer IMHO, and more effective.

Comment: @wvxvw: No, that's not how `[ ! ... ]` works. Try `if [ ! ... ] ; then echo foo ; else echo bar ; fi` for various values of `...`, such as `0` and `1`. You'll find that it always prints `bar`. The only time it would print `foo` is when `...` is blank (the empty string); for example, `if [ ! '' ] ; then echo foo ; fi` will print `foo`.

Comment: @wvxvw: Bash represents Booleans in a few different ways . . . it's pretty complicated, actually. In general, a command is supposed to end with an exit status that indicates whether it was successful: `0` for success, non-zero for error. Boolean-y things use "success" to be "true" and "error" to be "false", so something like `if foo ; then bar ; else baz ; fi` will run `bar` if `foo` returns `0` ("success/true") and `bar` if `foo` returns non-zero ("error/false"). (This sort of logic is used by `if`, `while`, `&&`, `||`, `!`, etc.) *[continued]*

Comment: @wvxvw: *[continued]* Consequently, and conversely, there are a number of commands that are really designed for use with `if` and so on, that return "success" when they mean "true" and "error" when they mean "false". For example, `[ "$a" = a ]` will return `0` ("success/true") if `$a` is `a`, and a nonzero value ("error/false") otherwise. So it all fits together nicely, hand-in-glove. Are you with me so far? But note that `[ ]`'s basic test, if you don't specify any other test, is, it just checks to see if it has a non-blank argument; and `!` negates that. *[continued]*

Comment: @wvxvw: *[continued]* So the use of `0` as a "true" exit status should not be taken to mean that `[ 1 ]` is "false"; rather, `[ 0 ]` and `[ 1 ]` both return `0` ("true"), and `[ ! 0 ]` and `[ ! 1 ]` both return a nonzero value ("false"), because `0` and `1` are both non-blank. By contrast, `[ ]` and `[ '' ]` are both false, and `[ ! ]` and `[ ! '' ]` are both true. So far, so good? Now, where it starts to get complicated is with arithmetic expressions. Inside an arithmetic expression, `0` means "false" and nonzero values mean "true" -- this is a legacy from C -- so *[continued]*

Comment: @wvxvw: *[continued]* `echo $(( 0 == 0 ))` will print `1` ("true") and `echo $(( 0 ? 1 : 2 ))` will print `2` (because `0` means "false"). And `for (( i = 0; 1 ; i++ )) ; do ... ; done` will loop forever, whereas `for (( i = 0; 0 ; i++ )) ; do ... ; done` will do nothing. So there are a few different concepts of "true" and "false", depending where in Bash you are, and some of them are the opposite of others of them. But that's not the worst of it: Bash will actually translate between them. `let 0` or `(( 0 ))` will have a nonzero exit status ("error/false"), because `0` is false *[continued]*

Comment: @wvxvw: *[continued]* inside an arithmetic expression, whereas `let 1` or `(( 1 ))` will have an exit status of `0` ("success/true"), because `1` is true inside an arithmetic expression. Does that all make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You bash script is very "imperative" as it has been rewritten from Assembly.

Another approach:

- get the descriptor file
- clean the descriptor file (leave mms://... strings in it)
- use that cleaned result as input for cyclic processing

This was a one liner, I just break it up. You'd put the code between the do..done. I didn't care about the file names being ginormous, I gave them as the output .wmv:

```
link="http://switch3.castup.net/cunet/gm.asp?ai=16&ip=79.180.37.230&course=c20478/2012b&cuud=user:77f6c69526b9fa05f78d3d6679630308d324d1043027b0720c295b93e4abb183&ar=c20478_12b_784_01_1&ticket=58353E7A69BF1B9XO655E9E683016C5255C08DD37211ECF495F72A64E5278AA434CSP3C10C028D604AAD6C39FE7D71386D230983BBAF58A2511D14222F95090AE2C4C55CB696B82919A5A8EB44EAF8954DEDB5"

for i in $(curl -s "$link" | awk '/mms/ {gsub (/<ref href="/, ""); gsub(/" \/>/, ""); print $0}')
do
  mplayer $i -dumpstream -dumpfile $i.wmv -vf scale=320:240
done
```